# Jqgrid and Custom button with dynamic values

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I have a small problem that maybe you guys can help me. I want to add a button to the grid that changes value depending on the line ie:

```
onSelectRow: function(id)
{
 jQuery('#organismos').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager1',{caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-image", title: "AO",onClickButton: function() {window.open('Hierarquia/tree_objetivos.php?idorg=' + id, '_blank');
}
```

Problem is that it will keep adding buttons. And what I wanted was for him to change value so each time you select a row. Have googled and asked for help in the forum and nobody helped me jqgrid. Someone can help me?

Comment: Why do you want it to work like that? Isn't it better to add button once and then on click grab the currently selected row id and display this new window (or show a warning if no row selected)?

Comment: @tpeczek Yes, it can also be so. Can you give me an example? I tried to access the id and change the value but I must have done something wrong. However ja tested so much, that was the last I put in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding button only once (after initializing the grid) and getting the selected row id from jqGrid options:

```
jQuery('#organismos').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager1', {
    caption: '',
    buttonicon: 'ui-icon-image',
    title: 'AO',
    onClickButton: function() {
        var selectedRowId = jQuery('#organismos').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        if (selectedRowId) {
            window.open('Hierarquia/tree_objetivos.php?idorg=' + encodeURIComponent(selectedRowId), '_blank');
        } else {
            alert('You need to select a row first!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thz mate, Good solution which unfortunately I never saw